# It is usually said that a Quantum field is a superposition of fields. How do we (in principle) acquire the probabilities for a certain configuration?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, probability, quantum-measurements

I read [This](http://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/11921990.pdf) paper by Baker, which talks about the interpretation of QFT. Essentially, the author looks for ontological "beings" that one can identify in QFT. The author argues that a fock space is unitarily equivalent to the space of classical field configurations.

However, the author also states that:

> "The resulting field interpretation will be called the wavefunctional
> interpretation. It holds that a state in QFT represents propensities
> for the manifestation of certain (classical) fields in the event of
> measurement."[P.7]

If this indeed the case, why do I never see a Field operator $\Phi$ being decomposed in projectors onto eigenspaces? In case of a scalar theory, I tried to calculate for example $\langle p | \Phi | p \rangle $, but I get the same value as for the vacuum expectation value. This doesn't seem like the right approach to obtain either the expectation value, or probabilities for field values.

On top of that, [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/176665/102243) answer deals with the paper, and states that:

> "The quantum field is, usually, considered to be an observable in a
> QFT (it is self-adjoint but unbounded, so often it would be affiliated
> to the W∗ algebra generated by its family of exponentials, the Weyl
> operators)"

This brings further confusion to me, because there are field operators that are clearly not self adjoint (for example the field operator of the dirac-field, or the field operator of the complex scalar field).

**Can there still be a probabilistic interpretation of a quantum field operator, although the field operator is not self adjoint? If so, how would one proceed to arrive there?** (I understand that the question is not of mutch interest for practitioneers, because scattering amplitudes are measurable just fine, I'm asking just for the good feeling of knowing that in principle, one could calculate this quantities, if one would like to).

If you answer, please consider the following: Can the confusion be lifted because the statement in the paper by Baker is only made on scalar fields?

I'm interested in free fields only, I'm aware that interacting fields get a whole lot more difficult, but I'd be happy if I at least had a nice picture of free fields in my head.

To say the last, I'm still an undergrad, and I'm kind of familiar with scalar fields and dirac fields. I'd be happy if a given answer can be understood by me conceptually.